# Como contabilizar o número de clientes que retornaram de um ano para o outro através do SQL?

Tags: sql, query, select

Tenho uma tabela `Serviços(Nro_Serv, Data, Cliente, Valor)` e gostaria de obter os clientes que fizeram serviço comigo em um ano X (ex: 2011) e que também fizeram em um ano Y (ex: 2012). Tentei usar `COUNT(*)` e depois `GROUP BY Cliente HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. Mas não tá dando um valor real.

Código do `SQL`:

```
SELECT cliente.nmcliente, COUNT(*) 
FROM ordemservico 
INNER JOIN cliente 
   ON ordemservico.cdcliente = cliente.cdcliente
WHERE ordemservico.auxordemservico = '/12' 
   OR ordemservico.auxordemservico = '/13'
GROUP BY cliente.nmcliente 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

O campo auxordemservico é um campo com sufixo do ano.

**Edição**
Alterei o `SQL` e fiz o seguinte:

```
SELECT cliente.nmcliente, ordemservico.auxordemservico, COUNT(*)
FROM ordemservico 
INNER JOIN cliente 
   ON ordemservico.cdcliente = cliente.cdcliente
WHERE ordemservico.auxordemservico = '/12' 
   OR ordemservico.auxordemservico = '/13'
GROUP BY cliente.nmcliente, ordemservico.auxordemservico
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Agora ele me retorna claramente **todos** os clientes que fizeram serviços nos dois anos. Eu preciso tirar primeiro os que não são duplicados, pois me interessa quem fez serviços nos dois anos. E depois disso aplicar um "Distinct".

Comment: Poderia adicionar à pergunta o SQL que você escreveu?

Comment: Se o campo ordemservico.auxordemservico tem o ano como prefixo não deveria começar pelo ano (2011 ou 2012 como você colocou na explicação)? Poste a definição de suas tabelas para facilitar quem deseja ajuda-lo.

Comment: @Osvaldo, foi mais para exemplo. Eu quero comparar dois anos diferentes.

Comment: @Strokes: não entendi sua explicação do campo ordemservico.auxordemservico, você diz que o ano é um prefixo mas coloca depois da barra (portanto seria um sufixo). Este é todo o conteúdo do campo ou apenas parte dele? A utilização do campo data, como proposto por Silvio Andorinha, não atende a suas necessidades?

Comment: @Osvaldo, ele representa um ano e é um sufixo (escrevi errado). Sim, esse "/12" e "/13" é o que ele armazena.

Comment: @Strokes: Quando você diz que não está dando um valor real é porque pode estar considerando os clientes que fizeram mais de um serviço em um único ano? Se for isso tente fazer um join com os que fizeram serviço em um ano "e" também com os que fizeram no outro ano.

Comment: @Osvaldo, eu acredito que ele retorne tanto os clientes que fizeram serviços nos anos de 2012 E 2013, assim como os que só fizeram em 2012 OU 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT(os1.cdcliente)
    FROM ordemservico os1
    WHERE os1.auxordemservico = '/12'
        AND EXISTS (
            SELECT os1.cdcliente
            FROM ordemservico os2
            WHERE os2.auxordemservico = '/13'
                AND os1.cdcliente = os2.cdcliente
        )
) AS temp_table
```

Ela busca linha por linha todos os registros de "/12" que também estão em "/13"

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa buscar pelo ano usando o `YEAR` que serve para extrair o ano em formato de string para você possa comparar, e dar um `group by` em Cliente por exemplo:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Servicos WHERE YEAR(Data)='2012' OR YEAR(Data)='2011' GROUP BY CLiente
```

esse select foi feito baseado nos dados em que você nos passou..

Comment: não consegui rodar:
SELECT * FROM ordemservico WHERE YEAR(ordemservico.dtabertura)='2012' || YEAR(ordemservico.dtabertura)='2011' GROUP BY ordemservico.cdcliente

O erro é esse: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, char 34.
YEAR.

Answer (score 0):

Desculpe meu erro. Tente:

```
SELECT cliente.nmcliente 
FROM cliente 
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.cdcliente FROM ordemservico o1 WHERE o1.auxordemservico = '/12') AS r1
   ON r1.cdcliente = cliente.cdcliente
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.cdcliente FROM ordemservico o1 WHERE o1.auxordemservico = '/13') AS r2
   ON r2.cdcliente = cliente.cdcliente
```

Devido aos INNER JOIN só selecionará aqueles que existem nos 2 anos.

Dependendo de seu SGBD você pode utilizar INTERSECT:

```
SELECT cliente.nmcliente
FROM cliente 
INNER JOIN 
    ((SELECT cdcliente FROM ordemservico WHERE auxordemservico = '/12')
        INTERSECT
    (SELECT cdcliente FROM ordemservico WHERE auxordemservico = '/13')) AS r
   ON cliente.cdcliente = r.cdcliente)
```

Veja 3 opções neste teste no SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c6186/11

Comment: infelizmente não rodou aqui. Segue mensagem de erro:
Column does not belong to referenced table.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -206.
Column unknown.
ORDEMSERVICO.AUXORDEMSERVICO.
unknown ISC error 336397208.

Comment: Também retornou um erro: Column does not belong to referenced table.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -206.
Column unknown.
O1.CDCLIENTE.
unknown ISC error 336397208.

Comment: "Consegui rodar" da seguinte maneira:

`SELECT cliente.nmcliente 
FROM cliente, ordemservico o1
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.cdcliente FROM ordemservico o1 WHERE o1.auxordemservico = '/12')
   ON o1.cdcliente = cliente.cdcliente
INNER JOIN (SELECT o1.cdcliente FROM ordemservico o1 WHERE o1.auxordemservico = '/13')
   ON o1.cdcliente = cliente.cdcliente`

Mas aparentemente assim o banco "trava" (processo para de responder). :(

Answer (score 0):

Adapta esse script para os campos da sua tabela.

O retorno é apenas o idCliente sem as repetições.

`select o.idCliente  from ordem as o where o.idCliente IN 
(SELECT 
    o.idCliente
from
    cliente as c
        inner join
    ordem as o ON c.idcliente = o.idCliente
where
     o.ano = '2013')
and o.ano = '2012'
group by o.idcliente;`

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir esse resultado podem-se empregar numerosas soluções, uma delas segue.

Suponha que existe o seguinte esquema de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE Servicos
(
  Nro_Serv int primary key,
  Data date,
  Cliente int,
  Valor float
);

INSERT INTO Servicos
(Nro_Serv, Data, Cliente, Valor)
VALUES
(1, '2011-03-01', 200, 53.66),
(2, '2011-03-05', 200, 108.90),
(3, '2012-01-25', 200, 85.45),
(4, '2012-02-09', 300, 785.45),
(5, '2013-11-09', 300, 77.45),
(6, '2014-01-22', 400, 87.45),
(7, '2011-03-05', 300, 778.90);
```

Baseado nesse esquema podemos empregar a seguinte consulta:

```
select cliente 
from Servicos 
where YEAR(data) = '2011' 
group by cliente
UNION
select cliente 
from Servicos 
where YEAR(data) = '2012' 
group by cliente
```

Basicamente existem duas consultas, cada qual agrupando por cliente e filtrando por ano. Então uma delas é para ano de 2011 e a outra para o ano de 2012 que ao final são unidas utilizando o operador UNION, que resulta no que se espera.

Para testar a proposta acima, veja tudo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aab7e/1).

Answer (score 0):

Aqui vai minha contribuição. Fiz testes e funcionou.

```
create table ORDEMSERVICO
(
    CDCLIENTE int,
    AUXORDEMSERVICO varchar(3)
);

insert into  ORDEMSERVICO values (12, '/12');
insert into  ORDEMSERVICO values (13, '/13');
insert into  ORDEMSERVICO values (25, '/12');
insert into  ORDEMSERVICO values (25, '/13');

select
  CDCLIENTE,
  sum(case when AUXORDEMSERVICO = '/12' then 1 else 0 end) as Ordem2012,
  sum(case when AUXORDEMSERVICO = '/13' then 1 else 0 end) as Ordem2013
from
  ORDEMSERVICO
group by 
  CDCLIENTE
having
  sum(case when AUXORDEMSERVICO = '/12' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
  sum(case when AUXORDEMSERVICO = '/13' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Qualquer coisa grita ai...
Simulado aqui:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4840d0/1